# How to make HTML elements not to span to second line if the container width is not sufficient?

Tags: css

I am adding textbox's and select elements dynamically, one after occupying the entire width of the container labels are added to the second line. But i don't want second line, insted i should get a horizontal scroll bar if the width of the container is not sufficient to accommodate all the labels

[image]

```
<div class="addContainer">    
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
```

Here is the link for for demo http://jsfiddle.net/5mwFL/

Comment: Add some HTML markup please.

Comment: use white-space:nowrap or keep min-width for the select box

Comment: overflow: hidden or scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5hxC/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:600px;
    height:60px;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}
input {
    height:26px;
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow:auto` for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

I think that works

Answer (score 0):

First, create a div inside .addContainer.

```
<div class="addContainer">   
<div class='wrapper'>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
<label class="select ">
    <select class="form-control" name="selecname" placeholder="" id="id1">
        <option value="1">Pass</option>
        <option value="0">Fail</option>
    </select><i></i>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Then apply the following CSS:

```
.addContainer {
    overflow: scroll; width: 500px; 
}
```

and give the wrapper div a very large width:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

If you can use JQuery, then you can dynamically create the width of .wrapper like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container_width = 65 * $(".wrapper label").length;
    $(".wrapper").css("width", container_width);
});
```

change 65 to the width of the label (I assumed that each label as a width of 65)

http://jsfiddle.net/5mwFL/1/